# How Do I Instantiate AnyGenerator<T> in Swift?

Tags: swift

So I'm trying to use `AnyGenerator` to wrap a generic `GeneratorType`, however I'm getting the error:

```
Argument passed to call that takes no argument
```

This seems to extend from a weird ambiguity as there is both an `AnyGenerator` struct (the one I expect) and an `AnyGenerator` class intended as an abstract class for implementations to extend.

However I don't have any idea how to specify one over the other, as all documentation I can find suggests I should just use:

```
let someGenerator = ["foo"].generate()
let anyGenerator = AnyGenerator(someGenerator)
```

Is there something else that I can do instead? For extra fun it seems there's also an `anyGenerator` global function, just to make sure no-one has any idea what's going on ;)

Comment: You should probably avoid the specific name `anyGenerator` _specifically_ since there exists a global native function `anyGenerator(..)` with the purpose of returning `AnyGenerator` for a given `Element`, [see this](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/func/anyGenerator/).

Comment: If you insist on calling your own variable "anyGenerator" then `let anyGenerator = Swift.anyGenerator(someGenerator)` would do the trick (not that I would recommend it :)

Comment: @MartinR Weirdly enough the dynamic type of the return from `anyGenerator(base:)` is not `AnyGenerator`, but an internal (?) type `_GeneratorBox<...>` ([see e.g. this](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/7bbb2228038e7604e619)), is this expected?

Comment: @dfri: I would consider that an implementation detail. – Anyway, things change again with Swift 2.2+. From https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md: *"Global anyGenerator() functions have been changed into initializers on AnyGenerator, making the API more intuitive and idiomatic.*

Comment: Ah, so the way I expected it to work is how it will work. Weird that it ended up inconsistent in this version of Swift when `AnySequence` and so-on work fine, I suppose maybe they missed it? I probably should use the beta Xcode version more, but I seem to write code that the Swift team loves to break with every update ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`anyGenerator<G : GeneratorType>(_: G)` function](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/func/anyGenerator/) to create your `AnyGenerator<...>` instance

> **signature:**
>
> ```
> func anyGenerator<G : GeneratorType>(base: G) -> AnyGenerator<G.Element>
> ```
>
> **description:**
>
> Return a `GeneratorType` instance that wraps `base` but whose type depends only on the type of `G.Element`.

Example:

```
struct Foo : GeneratorType {
    typealias Element = String
    mutating func next() -> String? {
        return "foo"
    }
}

var bar = anyGenerator(Foo())

func foofoo(bar: AnyGenerator<String>) {
    print("foobar")
}

foofoo(bar) // "foobar", ok
```

As I wrote in my comment to your question, you should probably avoid the specific name `anyGenerator` specifically since there exists a global native function `anyGenerator(..)`.

---

Also, please see @MartinR:s comment to your question above; the two global `anyGenerator` functions are soon-to-be deprecated (Swift 2.2), and will be removed in Swift 3.0, in favour of initializers on `AnyGenerator`.